# Index Out of Bounds Python in Neural Network script

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to python and this is (unfortunately) the first time I've wrote a relatively longer section of code in it.  I have been following a tutorial for writing a neural network but have run across an error message that I cannot seem to resolve.  I searched stack overflow for "IndexError: list index out of range" and understand that it's likely an error from trying to access a n-th element of a list that only has n-1 elements.  However, I can't determine which list is incorrect and how to fix.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and any way to run the script that would give me more information about which list is out of index would be super helpful.  Below are the error message and the code...

I keep getting the error message that reads,

```
(2, 2, 1)
[array([[ 0.09438987,  0.08228006, -0.00851927],
       [-0.09384243, -0.07417094,  0.1341281 ]]), array([[-0.20913607,  0.02783653, -0.07682221]])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BackProp.py", line 126, in <module>
    err = bpn.TrainEpoch(lvInput, lvTarget)
  File "BackProp.py", line 93, in TrainEpoch
    weightDelta = np.sum(layerOutput[None,:,:].transpose(2, 0, 1) * delta[delta_index][None,:,:].transpose(2, 1, 0), axis = 0)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

...and the code....

```
import numpy as np$
$
class BackPropagationNetwork:$
    """A back-propagation network"""$
$
    #$
    # Class Members$
    #$
    layerCount = 0$
    shape = None$
    weights = []$
$
    #$
    # Class Methods$
    #$
    def __init__(self, layerSize):$
        """Initialize the network"""$
$
        # Layer info$
        self.layerCount = len(layerSize) - 1$
        self.shape = layerSize$
$
        #Input/Output data from last Run$
        self._layerInput = []$
        self._layerOutput = []$
$
        # Create the weight arrays$
        for (l1, l2) in zip(layerSize[:-1], layerSize[1:]):$
            self.weights.append(np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size = (l2, l1+1)))$
$
    #$
    # Run Method$
    #$
    def Run(self, input):$
        """Run the network based on the input data"""$
$
        lnCases = input.shape[0]$
$
        #Clear out the previous intermediate value lists$
        self._layerInput = []$
        self._layerOutput = []$
$
        # Run it$
#$
    def Run(self, input):$
        """Run the network based on the input data"""$
$
        lnCases = input.shape[0]$
$
        #Clear out the previous intermediate value lists$
        self._layerInput = []$
        self._layerOutput = []$
$
        # Run it$
        for index in range(self.layerCount):$
            # Determine layer input$
            if index == 0:$
                layerInput = self.weights[0].dot(np.vstack([input.T, np.ones([1, lnCases])]))$
            else:$
                layerInput = self.weights[index].dot(np.vstack([self._layerOutput[-1], np.ones([1, lnCases])]))$
$
            self._layerInput.append(layerInput)$
            self._layerOutput.append(self.sgm(layerInput))$
$
        return self._layerOutput[-1].T$
$
    #$
    # TrainEpoch method$
    #$
    def TrainEpoch(self, input, target, trainingRate = 0.2):$
        """This method trains the network for one epoch"""$
$
        delta = []$
        lnCases = input.shape[0]$
$
        # First run the network$
        self.Run(input)$
$
        # Calculate our deltas$
        for index in reversed(range(self.layerCount)):$
            if index == self.layerCount - 1:$
                # Compare to the target values$
                output_delta = self._layerOutput[index] - target.T$
                error = np.sum(output_delta**2)$
                delta.append(output_delta * self.sgm(self._layerInput[index], True))$
            else:$
                # compare to the following layer's delta$
                delta_pullback = self.weights[index + 1].T.dot(delta[-1])$
                delta.append(delta_pullback[:-1, :] * self.sgm(self._layerInput[index], True))$
            # Compute weight deltas$
            for index in range(self.layerCount):$
                delta_index = self.layerCount - 1 - index$
$
                if index == 0:$
                    layerOutput = np.vstack([input.T, np.ones([1, lnCases])])$
                else:$
                    layerOutput = np.vstack([self._layerOutput[index - 1], np.ones([1, self._layerOutput[index - 1].shape[1]])])$
$
                weightDelta = np.sum(layerOutput[None,:,:].transpose(2, 0, 1) * delta[delta_index][None,:,:].transpose(2, 1, 0), axis = 0)$
                self.weights[index] -= trainingRate * weightDelta$
$
            return error$
$
$
$
$
$
$
    # Transfer Functions$
    def sgm(self, x, Derivative=False):$
        if not Derivative:$
            return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))$
        else:$
            out = self.sgm(x)$
            return out*(1-out)$
$
$
#$
# If run as a script, create a test object$
#$
if __name__ == "__main__":$
    bpn = BackPropagationNetwork((2,2,1))$
    print(bpn.shape)$
    print(bpn.weights)$
$
    lvInput = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [0,1], [1,0]])$
    lvTarget = np.array([[0.05], [0.05], [0.95], [0.95]])$
$
    lnMax = 100000$
    lnErr = 1e-5$
    for i in range(lnMax-1):$
        err = bpn.TrainEpoch(lvInput, lvTarget)$
        if i % 2500 == 0:$
            print("Iteration {0}\tError: {1:0.6f}".format(i, err))$
        if err <= lnErr:$
            print("Minimum error reached at iteration {0}".format(i))$
            break$
$
    # Display output$
    lvOutput = bpn.Run(lvInput)$
    print("Input: {0}\nOutput: {1}".format(lvInput, lvOutput))$
$
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second for loop in `TrainEpoch` is indented too far, and that's what's causing the `IndexError`. In other words, the line which reads:

```
for index in range(self.layerCount):
```

should be at the same indentation level as the other for loop:

```
for index in reversed(range(self.layerCount)):
```